# Will the background component unmount when modal is open in react? If not, how to maintain/store states of modal and react component using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, modal-dialog, material-ui

Demo ( not working but for file structure)
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-bsr06

1. I need to open a Modal when I clicked something in this URL  `dashboard/someMails`, it should open with `dashboard/someMails/:id`.
2. I want to maintain the states of someMmails pages' one of the emails and that particular email's modal and visa versa
3. In React router I switch

```
     <Switch>
       <Route path="dashboard/someMails" component={EmailsHome} />
       <Route path="dashboard/someMails/:id" component={EmailModal} />
     </Switch>`
```

4. Since I need to maintain states, storing states in reducer(redux).
5. But when to store is the question.

   a) Can I store when componentUnMounts? 
   b) Will the component unmount when modal is open?
   c) If component will not unmount should I keep triggering reducer method to store each and every time state change in `EmailsHome` or `EmailModal`?

Comment: Coder see my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component will unmount when you navigate to the modal route. That being said, you should avoid executing logic inside `componentWillUnmount()` other than clean-up methods.

It looks like you want to update some `state` in `redux` when a user clicks on a email, causing them to navigate to different `route` and open a modal.

If that is the case, you should trigger this action in the `onClick()` handler of the `Link` that sends them to another page.

I've created a basic template on how you can achieve this feature: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-wpisp

The integral pieces are here:

### Email.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateEmail } from "./emailActions";

const Email = props => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(props.read);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        style={{ background: "transparent", border: "none" }}
        onClick={() => props.updateEmail(props.id, checked)}
      >
        <Link to={`/dashboard/someMails/${props.id}`}>{props.message}</Link>
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)}>Mark As Read</button>
      <p>{checked ? "Read" : "Unread"}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateEmail: (id, value) => {
      dispatch(updateEmail(id, value));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Email);
```

1. When you click "Mark As Read" that will toggle the "checked" state
   of the Email component.
2. Follow-up by clicking the link, it will call our action-creator,
   which will pass in the id of the message and the state-value
   (true or false).
3. Redux, which is holding our array of messages, updates the message
   with matching id, and it gets the state-value we configured inside
   our component. Setting the "read" value to be (true or false).

### EmailModal.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getEmail } from "/emailActions";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const EmailModal = ({ emails, getEmail, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = match.params.id;
    getEmail(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/dashboard/someMails">Back to emails</Link>
      <h4>Message: {emails.currentEmail.message}</h4>
      <h4>Read:{"" + emails.currentEmail.read}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    emails: state.emails
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getEmail: id => {
      dispatch(getEmail(id));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(EmailModal);
```

1. The component mounts, we call an action-creator to find the email
   in Redux with the same id of the one in our url.
2. We display that email, and now depending on whether or not you
   changed the state of the email in the previous page (read or
   unread), it will get that updated value and display it in the modal.

To summarize, yes you can execute redux-logic while React is in the process of navigating to another Route. In this, we passed some component state-value to an action-creator, it updated redux-state and when we finally navigated to the modal component, it got the updated value.